# Java - Error: Cannot find symbol after try...catch (fileContent[0])

Tags: java

```
public class ShowDoMilhao {

//constructor of the class
public ShowDoMilhao()
{

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    //string to hold name of txt file
    String file1 = "Facil.txt";

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //Storing file into an array of strings
    try {
       //creating an object (an instance of ReadFile class)
       ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file1);

       String[] fileContent = new String[file.readLines()];
       fileContent = file.OpenFile();  

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   

    System.out.println(fileContent[0]);                
}   //end of main method   
}//end of class
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. Fica dificil ajudar sem saber exatamente sua dificuldade. Clique em **[edit]** e formule melhor a pergunta, expondo o que não está conseguindo fazer.

Comment: fileContent não existe fora do try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro ocorre por quê você está tentando acessar `fileContent` fora do `try catch`.

Declare a variavel antes para que seja acessível:

```
public class ShowDoMilhao {

    public ShowDoMilhao() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String file1 = "Facil.txt";

        String[] fileContent;
        try {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file1);

            fileContent = new String[file.readLines()];
            fileContent = file.OpenFile();

        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println(fileContent[0]);
    }
}
```

Note que eu realizei a declaração da variável fora do `try catch`, sem isso ela fica visível somente no escopo do `try catch`

Comment: Legal, entendi o erro... Muito obrigado